# How can i alter the HEIGHT of PANEL in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, height

How do I reduce the height of a panel in jquery mobile?

```
$(function(){
      $('#payable_panel').css('width','60%');
      $('#payable_panel').css('height','30px');
}
```

I've tried using this code, but it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/10/

Answer (score 0):

In JQM panel the min-height is 100%. So Try like the following in your style sheet.

```
.ui-panel{
   min-height: 200px !important;
}
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/10/)